# How to set the CSS styles for the slider thumb in Chrome/Safari?

Tags: css, google-chrome, slider

This does not work:

```
input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    background-color: green;
}
```

I can't set styles for the slider thumb in Chrome/Safari. How do I do it?

Comment: add jsfiddle/snippet/something

Comment: doesn't server your purpose?! your purpose is to get help. if you want help - provide the required basics.

Comment: I really apologize. It did not come out well. My point is, as in my answer, is that the -webkit, -moz, or -ms styles for the slider-thumb can't be used in the sites I am working on and aren't recommended in most cases. Please see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-slider-thumb

Comment: that really not true.

Comment: This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-slider-thumb

Comment: I edited my answer to be more accurate, as some -moz, -webkit, or -ms styles may work standardized. I am not sure.

Comment: They will work/not-work based on the browser (and not based on the website).

Comment: Correct, that is what I meant to say. And why it seems they should not be used on production sites.

Comment: actually a lot of people use this on production. You just need to know that not all browsers will look the same (you can check how gmail looks on ie7-8-9-10-11/firefox/chrome/safari). The differences are mostly due to using of non-standard features.

Answer (score 0):

So I came across this answer here:
This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-slider-thumb